# coreData only printing last entity (swift4)

Tags: ios, core-data, label, fetch, swift4

I am trying to call all of my entries of coreData .color. The problem is only 1 entry of coreData is being called to the label. I would like all of the entities of coreData to be printed on the label not just the latest one, which the code is currently doing.

```
  import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

    var users = [User]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        tableView.dataSource = self

        if CDHandler.fetchObject() != nil {
            users = CDHandler.fetchObject()!
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return users.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        cell.textLabel?.text = users[indexPath.row].username
        for c in users {

            label.text = c.color
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your current loop sets the last item of the array to the label text , so Try this to append values together

```
  for c in users {

        label.text = "\((label.text)!)+\((c.color)!)" 
    }
```

Comment: This does not work. I am getting this issue String interpolation produces a debug description for an optional value; did you mean to make this explicit?

Comment: I don’t know what you mean

Comment: click the red icon that shows the error and it will handle the code automatically

Comment: Its not a red icon its a yellow issue.

Comment: it's a warning that if a text contains say qwe string it will be printed Optional("qwe")